# How to set title and class in the HTML for the options of a ModelChoiceField?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to render a ModelChoiceField for that model that looks like:

```
<select name="mymodel" id="id_mymodel">
    <option value="1" title="Value 1" class="">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2" title="Value 2" class="Value 1">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

The differences between this output and the default output for a `ModelChoiceField` are the title and class elements in the OPTION tag. They don't exist in `ModelChoiceField`'s default output.

For my purposes:

- The title element is supposed to be the Option Name.
- The class element is supposed to be `self.parent.name`. (**this is my problem**)

So, in the HTML snippet above, Value 1 has no parent and Value 2 has a parent of Value 1.

What is the best mechanism to change `ModelChoiceField`'s default HTML output?

---

**EDIT:** I understand how to create a new Widget for rendering HTML. The problem is how to render a value from the underlying model in each of the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your own widget:

```
from django.forms.widgets import Select 

class MySelect(Select):

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=(), model):
       self.model = model
       super(Select, self).__init__(attrs)

    def render_options(self, choices, selected_choices):
        def render_option(option_value, option_label):
            option_value = force_unicode(option_value)
            option = self.model.objects.get(pk=option_value)
            selected_html = (option_value in selected_choices) and u' selected="selected"' or ''
            return u'<option value="%s"%s class="%s">%s</option>' % (
                escape(option_value), selected_html,
                str(obj.parent.name),
                conditional_escape(force_unicode(option_label)))
        # Normalize to strings.
        selected_choices = set([force_unicode(v) for v in selected_choices])
        output = []
        for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
            if isinstance(option_label, (list, tuple)):
                output.append(u'<optgroup label="%s">' % escape(force_unicode(option_value)))
                for option in option_label:
                    output.append(render_option(*option))
                output.append(u'</optgroup>')
            else:
                output.append(render_option(option_value, option_label))
        return u'\n'.join(output)
```

If you also want to chance the field's label: the field class has a method `label_from_instance`.

Comment: I don't think you saw the edit to my question (posted minutes before you added your answer). How do you propose I access the underlying model to obtain the parent information?

Comment: If you look at my code: You pass the underlying model to the widget when you initialize it and get the parent (and other information) via  option = self.model.objects.get(pk=option_value), then you can render any of the information in this option object; isn't that what you wanted? and yes i read your edit and understood it like that...

Comment: Sorry, I should have read your code way closer than I did. I upvoted you. I would rather have a solution that would not hit the db once for every option though... I think I'm going to adapt your idea and pass a dict with the values I need into the widget.

Comment: well yes i made it just quick and dirty. but get all options in a dict and get the right one for every iteration...

Answer (score 1):

Look at my example about how to create custom fields in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975198/limit-choices-in-the-drop-down-of-subcategory-based-on-related-category-in-django/2981557#2981557)

Comment: See the edit to my question. Thanks, but the problem is not just rendering some markup, but rendering data from the underlying object in the markup.