# Django ModelForm filtering ForeingKey

Tags: django, forms, filter, modelform

I have this:

**In models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Description

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Description

class Smartgrid(models.Model):
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    Subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    Descriptor = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Descriptor
```

**In forms.py:**

```
class SmartgridForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Smartgrid
```

**In views.py**

```
def new_point(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = SmartgridForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/gis')
    else:
        form = SmartgridForm()

    return render_to_response('SmartgridForm.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**The question:**

I want that once the user choose the category in SmartgridForm.html, the Subcategory field only display these subcategory with category = category selected

Thanks !!!!

JDC.

Comment: You need to upgrade your search skills:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189572/most-djangonic-solution-for-category-subcategory-product-select-form][1]


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975198/limit-choices-in-the-drop-down-of-subcategory-based-on-related-category-in-djang][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189572/most-djangonic-solution-for-category-subcategory-product-select-form
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975198/limit-choices-in-the-drop-down-of-subcategory-based-on-related-category-in-djang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this solution if you don't want to use another app: [Django/jQuery Cascading Select Boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233850/django-jquery-cascading-select-boxes)

But for me, it's better to use Dajax 
http://www.dajaxproject.com/forms/

Comment: Ok Thanks, I have read about it, but finally I used the app Django Smart Selects
(https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)

It is easy and fine.
Thank you !!!